# Euler's Formula: $V-E+F=2$ by using spheric triangles

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, spherical-geometry

I just have a question to a proof found here: https://nrich.maths.org/1384

At one point it says:

> As eight copies of $\triangle$ will fill the sphere without
>   overlapping.

Why this? Why can I "split" up a sphere into 8 identically triangles, of which any angle is $90°$ (so the angle-sum of a triangle is 270°) ?

Later it says

> the total angle sum is $2\pi V$

(V... vertices). Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three coordinate planes cut the sphere into eight triangles $\Delta$.

The sum of the angles at each vertex of the triangulation is $2\pi$.

I think this was not terribly difficult $\ldots$